# Assigned task cannot be reassigned or unassigned in optaplanner task assignment process

Tags: optaplanner

I want help regarding Optaplanner task assignment changes.

I have 10 tasks 5 customer and 4 employees, In 10 tasks i run optaplanner it assigned 10 task to 5 employees. Again i have produced 5 task and run optaplanner. It removed already assigned task and reassigned that task to other employee.

How can i stop the reassigned or unassigned task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@PlanningPin` (see docs) or `immableEntityFilter` (see docs), you can pin assignments during repeated planning (such as continuous planning) so OptaPlanner doesn't change those entities but still respects them for the constraints.

That being said, task assignment is a using a chained variable and there is a pitfall with pinning there: if an entity is pinned, the previous entity must be pinned too (all the way back to the anchor).